# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras', but terminal tells me that i have

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Running machine learning python from (https://github.com/cyrixninja/Waste-Classifier-V2). This gives me an error below. However, I can confirm my tensorflow by pip3 show tensorflow and just in case, I re-installed tensorflow here. But No Module error is alerting too many times.

python3 plastic_classifier.py

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plastic_classifier.py", line 6, in <module>
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

pip3 show tensorflow

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.12.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astor, gast, grpcio, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, numpy, protobuf, six, tensorboard, termcolor, wheel
Required-by:
```

pip install tensorflow-macos

```
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.1 absl-py-1.2.0 astunparse-1.6.3 flatbuffers-1.12 gast-0.4.0 google-auth-2.11.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.47.0 h5py-3.7.0 keras-2.9.0 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 libclang-14.0.6 markdown-3.4.1 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-3.19.4 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 rsa-4.9 tensorboard-2.9.1 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.1 tensorflow-estimator-2.9.0 tensorflow-macos-2.9.2 termcolor-1.1.0 werkzeug-2.2.2 wrapt-1.14.1
```

pip install tensorflow-metal

```
Successfully installed tensorflow-metal-0.5.1
```

I would leave some information that I tried https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-mac-metal-jul-2021.ipynb

System information

- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): macOS
- Monterey 12.3.1 TensorFlow version: 1.12.0 Python version: 3.10.6
- Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?

Comment: I'm not sure enough to post this as an answer, but I don't think that keras was bundled in Tensorflow v1. I think it's possible that the code you're trying to run requires tf v2

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense since you say you have tensorflow 1.12, but also installed tensorflow 2.9? Likely you have multiple Python versions/environments and are mixing things up.

Comment: Is the correct virtual environment activated? Could you verify that within the activated environment there is tensorflow and keras installed. [this](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-keras-and-tensorflow/) is a nice article on installing the latest tensorflow version (bottom line: tensorflow is still automatically accompanied by keras)

Comment: There could be a reason tensorflow not installed in your system properly. Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip/) link to install tensorflow as per your system OS. Also you need to install the right TF version as per the installed Python version. Refer to this [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux) for more details.